# Changing the user-agent

Tags: php, user-agent

Well, I have the following problem. I made a tool that checks the status of a website.

For example if I enter www.youtube.com it will say

`http://www.youtube.com  HTTP/1.0 200 OK`

and for a website with a redirect it will say:

```
http://www.imgur.com    HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
http://imgur.com/       HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Alright, this works just as it should, however I would like to make it so that you can select the user-agent. So for example Android or something. Because youtube on android will redirect to `m.youtube.com`

I made a dropdownlist already with different user-agents and now what I don't know is how to change a user-agent. When I search google it just gives me browser plugins or addons.

I hope someone knows of a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request in the first place...?

Comment: @deceze I use get_headers for the header information. and getBrowser(); for the other information, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a CURL request and change the user agent like this.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Comment: This seems to work. I will see if it works with my dropdownlist and different selections. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well i've been playing around alot but I don't think it worked. I've added the whole curl thing, like curl_init. but when i set the useragent and let it echo the useragent it still is the chrome browser